# How to concat two rows into string from a result set in MySql?

Tags: mysql

Basicly this is my mysql query:

```
select distinct(shipment_tag) from ir_shipment_registry where shipment_id = '2020111'
```

and the result set:

```
| shipment_tag |
+--------------+
|  Truck       |
|  Equipment   |
|              |
```

How can I concat the two result set into string so that i can assign it to a variable? I tried

```
SET @purchasetype = (select distinct(shipment_tag) from ir_shipment_registry where shipment_id = '2020111')
```

but it returns and error says: `Subquery returns more than 1 row.`

I want something in my variable like : `@purchasetype = "Truck, Equipment".`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps use `GROUP_CONCAT` here:

```sql
SET @purchasetype = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(shipment_tag SEPARATOR ', ') FROM ir_shipment_registry WHERE shipment_id = '2020111');
```

Comment: is this possible with group by? for example selecting a large amount of data and group  by shipment_id.

Comment: Define "this" and also "possible."  That would be asking another question IMHO.